# VCL-Styles menu hotkey inconsistency

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I've noticed that when VCL-Styles is enabled, items in menu will be selected with hotkeys *even without Alt-key is pressed*.

This interferes with the rest of my user interface and I find it very strange that a styles library change the behavior of hotkeys.

Can I remove this inconsistency somehow?

Normal: Pressing "A" does not activate the main menu (Alt + A does).

[image: Normal: Pressing "A" does not activate the main menu (Alt + A does).]

Styled: Pressing "A" activates the main menu. *Note: no Alt key*.

[image: Styled: Pressing "A" activates the main menu.]

My test project is [here](http://www.emix8.org/files/vclstylemainmenuhotkeys.zip) in case anyone wants to try it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue it seems related to the `TFormStyleHook.CMDialogChar` method which handle the message CM_DIALOGCHAR, the original method is not checking if the key <kbd>Alt</kbd> is  pressed.

I wrote this style hook, which resolves the issue.

```
type
  TFormStyleHookFix= class (TFormStyleHook)
  procedure CMDialogChar(var Message: TWMKey); message CM_DIALOGCHAR;
  end;

  TFormStyleHookHelper= class  helper for TFormStyleHook
  private
     function CheckHotKeyItem(ACharCode: Word): Boolean;
  end;



{ TFormStyleHookFix }

procedure TFormStyleHookFix.CMDialogChar(var Message: TWMKey);
begin
   if ((Message.KeyData and $20000000) <> 0 ) and (CheckHotKeyItem(Message.CharCode)) then
    begin
      Message.Result := 1;
      Handled := True;
    end
end;

{ TFormStyleHookHelper }
function TFormStyleHookHelper.CheckHotKeyItem(ACharCode: Word): Boolean;
begin
  Result:=False;
  if Self.FMainMenuBarHook<>nil then
   Result:=Self.FMainMenuBarHook.CheckHotKeyItem(ACharCode);
end;
```

use in this way

```
 TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TForm9, TFormStyleHookFix);
```

Remeber report this case to the [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com/) Page.

Comment: +1 And once again VCL styles has bugs. The quality of this part of the VCL is quite dire.

Comment: Agreed David. But we have to post quality central bugs or it won't get any better!

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo! It seems you can fix all vcl-styles related problems :-) Everyone please vote here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=104588

Comment: do u maybe know if THotKey in Xe8 has VCL Style problem? : http://www.sql.ru/forum/1230576